# AS400 style naming over JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ibm-midrange, jt400

Is there any way I can use AS400 style library/file style naming over JDBC with jt400?  I want to be able to run queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM MYLIBRARY/MYFILE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Set the jdbc naming property to "system".

http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen_6_3/com/ibm/as400/access/doc-files/JDBCProperties.html

Comment: this also enables the library list lookup.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to depend on the driver you use. For our .NET projects we use the IBM drivers and we use the "standard" iSeries naming convention.

Check the options in the driver. We have "Naming=System" within our connection string (again using the .NET driver) Perhaps that will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do this on the 400 with STRSQL but not as far as I know with JDBC